# TypeScript Chrome extension "Duplicate function implementation."

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a chrome extension with multiple content scripts using typescript (I'm new to both js and ts). Inside of the content scripts I have two functions with the same name. I basically need to know how to "allow" this:

```
//FileA:
function methodxyz(param: Element): void {

//FileB:
function methodxyz(param: Element): void {
```

I have read in other articles to either put `export { };` on the top of my file or to put `export` in front of my functions. But then I get an error when using my extension that says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` or something similar.

I think there is an option in typescript to combine all of your files into one .js file which I would assume causes that error to be thrown, but as I don't want that functionality I hope someone can help me with this :)

Comment: If you have two functions with the same name do they do they perform the same function?

Comment: a similar function (hence the same name) but as they are to be executed on different pages they are not the same

Comment: Then call them different names?

Comment: I don't know what the term minifying means but if you mean combining multiple ts files into one js file that is NOT what I'm doing (as I said in the question). I am aware I could just rename them but I was interested if there is a cleaner solution in general

Comment: A cleaner solution to just renaming the functions? Probably not. (Minifying basically [compresses the code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).)

Comment: I thought that I could do something like defining a scope so that the two content scripts are totally independent of each other (as they should be). It just feels like something that should be possible in a clean way

Comment: OK. Let me put it this way: you've spent more time on asking this question, and responding to me in the comments, than you have just _renaming your files_. The warning is telling you what the issue is, but for some reason you're not listening to it.

Comment: why would I rename my files? I am so sorry I want to maybe improve my code and learn something in the process

Comment: All I want to understand is why I shouldn't be able to declare a function with the same name in two completely seperate files

Comment: [This any help](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56068)?

Comment: No, I already have such a config file

Comment: How are you currently getting those files together as one? Typescript has `Namespaces` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing but an easier way would be to simply use ES Modules and export your functions. Then import the function you need.
Since es modules are a "new" feature chromes extensions might not support them. The best way would be to use sth. like babel to transpile your code to ES5.

Comment: @MatthiasS thank you for your link, adding such a namespace around my content script did resolve the issue. If you want you can put this as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript has [Namespaces](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing) for that.

From reading the comments, just wanted to say something on JS & TS. I think an important thing to understand about javascript is that there are a lot of different runtimes going around (different browser versions, node versions, etc.), and they don't all support all the latest features of the language specification, which are defined in the ECMAScript Language Specification.

So as a developer, to be able to use the newest features of the language, while not worrying about being compatible with every runtime that is going to run my code, you can transpile your code into an older version to make it compatible. That brings the advantage that you can program with the newest, flashy things.

You can take a look at https://babeljs.io/

Once you do that, you can follow more JS standards instead of namespaces by writing your code as `Modules`, which is something supported natively in JS and TS.
[Read about modules in TS.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

It has already been mentioned several times above, but if you can know exactly whether a file has duplicate variable or function names, you can wrap the entire code in a namespace.

Below is an example. (Simply wrap your code in namespace and curly braces.)

```js
namespace foo {
  // your content script or anything
}
```

In addition, when developing a Chrome extension program, if there is a possibility that some codes may have duplicate variable or function names, you can help the IDE by using the same namespace